# How to inherit the base controller method from the base app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I've created a base app that contains a base controller, that looks as the following:
[image]

Everytime, when I create a new app, I would like to inherit the base app to the new app to use the `BaseController.js` and so I can avoid creating `BaseController.js` everytime on the new app.

This is the way, how I use `BaseController.js`:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "com/example/BaseApp/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseCtrl) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseCtrl.extend("com.example.BaseApp.controller.View1", {
        onInit: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

How can I inherit the base app to a new app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve this by creating a library which is used by all your applications.

In that library you can then create a `Basecontroller.js`, which will be your starting point for the specific controllers of your applications.

In order for this to work you'll need to create a library, use it in your application and change the used `Basecontroller` in your specific controller, to the `Basecontroller` you created in your library:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "name/space/to/library/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (BaseController, JSONModel) {

});
```

to create a library you could eg. check the following:

1) https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/15/step-by-step-procedure-to-create-sapui5-library-with-custom-controls-and-consume-the-library-into-sapui5-applications/

Comment: How to create a library project?

Comment: check the links I included in the post, I used the second link at the time but link (1) has more upvotes so you could check these :)

Comment: Both links are the same at the moment

Comment: thanks, probably was trying my luck in multi-tasking ;)